# 301 Redirect with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have some SEO to do on my site.
I'd like that the page 'red-bags' point to the search page 'search.php?keyword=red bags'
In addittion I'd like that the old search page makes a 301 redir to the new red-bags.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^red-bags /search\.php/keyword=red\sbags [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} keyword=red\sbags
RewriteRule ^search.php http://www.mysite.com/red-bags [R=301,L]
```

The second rules not work. Please help.

Comment: http://lifeonubuntu.com/how-to-debug-apache-rewriterule-or-mod_rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the second rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} keyword=red%20bags
RewriteRule ^search.php http://www.mysite.com/red-bags? [R=301,L]
```

In the first line the space is changed to the urlencoded %20
The question mark at the end of red-bags strips off the query string, otherwise it would have automatically been appended to the new url.

Comment: Ok, now the second rule was checked. But the redirect going in loop.